# .count as count_all doesn't return the variable name.

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method which returns appointments. However, for this particular bit I'm looking to return only the number of appointments for any given day.

The logs show that I retrieve the data, but I seem unable to display it. It seems that the data I retrieve gets returned without any name to access it.

> NoMethodError (undefined method `date_startdate' for ["2014-03-29", 2]:Array)

even though the SQL statement says:

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE(startDate) AS date_startdate FROM
>   "appointments" WHERE (garage == 't') GROUP BY DATE(startDate)

Here is my method

```
 def get_appointment_count
        @appointments_count = Appointment.where("garage == ?", true).group("DATE(startDate)").count.to_a

        appointments = []
        #render :text => @appointments.to_json
        @appointments_count.each do |appointment|


            appointments << {
                :id => 1,
                :title => 'Taken',
                :description => 'count_all',
                :start => appointment.date_startdate,
                :end => appointment.date_startdate,
                :allDay => true,
                :editable => true
            }
        end

        render :text => appointments.to_json
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `count`, because count after grouping returns object like `{value_of_grouped_field => count}`

```
@appointments_count = Appointment.where("garage == ?", true).group("DATE(startDate)").to_a
```

if you need to know how many elements are in `@appointments_count` you can apply `size` after converting it to array (`.to_a`)